# Grab value from parse column into label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, swift4.2

I have made a small app that uses [Parse](https://www.back4app.com/), I have a signUp viewController, and after signing up I have a `usersVC` viewController.

Inside Parse dashboard I added a column named `profileName`, I want that after signing up to grab the value that is inside this column to some label.

Here parse dashboard:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACIMR.png)

I mean I need something like: `profileNameLbl.text = PFUser.current().profileName`

but of course this wont compile.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the page [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Probably you still want to edit your question then, primary I think about some additional code of your efforts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On swift 4.2 use:

```
PFUser.current()?[“profileName”] as? String
```